# errror trying to create trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to execute this query on mysql using phpmyadmin

```
 CREATE TRIGGER complete_ride
 AFTER INSERT ON completed_ride
 FOR EACH ROW 
    when(NEW.status = 'OK') then
    BEGIN
    UPDATE driver SET n_successes = n_successes + 1
    WHERE person_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM vehicle WHERE plate = NEW.plate);
    UPDATE passenger SET n_successes = n_successes + 1
    WHERE person_id = NEW.passenger_id;
    UPDATE driver SET wallet = wallet + NEW.amount
    WHERE person_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM vehicle WHERE plate = NEW.plate);
    END
```

but I get:

```
#1064 - Syntax error near 'when(NEW.status = 'OK') then
    BEGIN
    UPDATE driver SET n_successes = ...' line 4
```

any solution? thanks

Comment: WHEN is I think ORACLE searched_case_expression:and does not exist in mysql - mysql equivalent is if..then..end if. Be wary of trying to use code from other rdbms in mysql.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use an IG and not an wHEN

I changed the WHERE clause, i don't know exactly

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER complete_ride
 AFTER INSERT ON completed_ride
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
   IF (NEW.status = 'OK') then

        UPDATE driver SET n_successes = n_successes + 1
        WHERE person_id = (SELECT driver_id 
                         FROM vehicle 
                         WHERE plate = NEW.plate);
        UPDATE passenger SET n_successes = n_successes + 1
        WHERE person_id = NEW.passenger_id;
        UPDATE driver SET wallet = wallet + NEW.amount
        WHERE person_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM vehicle WHERE plate = NEW.plate);
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```